# Kerberos authentication in the Angular application with backend in the form of RESTful services

Tags: angular, spring-boot, single-sign-on, kerberos

In the project I have to do SSO using Kerberos. The project consists of a frontend made in Angular (the latest stable) [run on nginx] and backend made using Spring-Boot. Backend is providing the REST API.

What should the authentication architecture be? Should the frontend communicate with Kerberos? What should he send to Backend then?

Do you have any example of Kerberos in Angular and can you share it? 
How do you configure Spring Security then?
Do I need keytab? How to generate id?

Comment: This may help you https://mherman.org/blog/token-based-authentication-with-angular/

Comment: What is the container running the Boot application?

Comment: Spring-Boot uses as a default Tomcat. We did not chagned it.

Comment: Any updates of question?